# Issues with function event - FireFox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've recently taken over a project from a previous developer and I'm stuck on the below error that occurs on FireFox only. I'm quite useless when it comes to jQuery so I'm hoping it's a relatively easy fix.

I'm getting event is undefined for the service_init function. Any ideas? I've tried adding

```
event = event || window.event;
```

and have also added the event parameter to the function

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    var $serviceClick = jQuery(".service-selector a");
    var $serviceBox = jQuery(".post-content-ajax");
    var $random = $serviceClick.eq([Math.floor(Math.random()*$serviceClick.length)]);

    function service_init(event) {
        event = event || window.event;
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
        jQuery(".post-content-ajax").css('display', 'none');
        $dataTarget = $random.data('service');
        $random.removeClass('active-service').addClass('active-service');
        jQuery("#" + $dataTarget).css('display', 'block');
        jQuery(this).addClass('active-service');
        jQuery(this).prev().removeClass('active-service');
    }
    service_init();

    jQuery($serviceClick).click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();            
        jQuery($serviceClick).removeClass('active-service');
        $dataTarget = jQuery(this).data('service');
        jQuery(".post-content-ajax").css('display', 'none');
        jQuery("#" + $dataTarget).css('display', 'block');
        jQuery(this).addClass('active-service');
        jQuery(this).prev().removeClass('active-service');


    });
});
```

Comment: Why do you expect it to exist? That isn't an event handler.

Comment: The reason for the error is because `window.event` does not exist in Firefox, and you're not providing any parameter to the function. Presumably you should remove `service_init()` and do this instead: `jQuery($serviceClick).click(service_init).trigger('click')`, however that's a complete guess as you've not said what the code should actually be doing.

Comment: Drop your first 3 lines in `service_init` ... and its argument parameter `event`

Comment: @LGSon that will still leave the reference to `this` though.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I missed those...they need to go as well (or be replaced)

Comment: Maybe `service_init` is used somewhere else as an event handler? if so just wrap the `event` inside an if like so: `if(event){ event.stopPropagation(); event.preventDefault; }` and problem solved